# Attach ASP.NET's RegularExpressionValidator to an INPUT created by some javascript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, validation

I've got an ASP.NET page that includes an asp:TextBox with a RegularExpressionValidator attached, and some JavaScript that creates an INPUT textbox (among other things) on the page.

I'd like to attach another RegularExpressionValidator onto that new INPUT without going back to the web server. Is this possible?

Many thanks.

(Search fodder follows. These validators would have the same issue.)
RequiredFieldValidator
CompareValidator
RangeValidator
CustomValidator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those field validators (being server controls) generate javascript and send it to the page.  I would look at the generated javascript.  I have looked, but not that closely.  I bet there is a way for you to generate your own javascript that would set the appropriate properties to override the settings that were generated on the server.